# how to take average for each portion of an array

Tags: arrays, matlab, numpy, vectorization, mean

Say I have a `500000x1` array called `A`. I want to divide this array into `1000` equal sections, and then calculate the mean of that section. So I will end up with a `1000x1` array called `B`, in which `B[1]` is the mean of `A[1:500]`, `B[2]` is the mean of B[501:1000]`, and so on. Since I will be doing this many many times, I want to do it efficiently. What's the most effective way of doing this in Matlab/Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NumPy/Python**

We could reshape to have `500` columns and then compute average along the second axis -

```
A.reshape(-1,500).mean(axis=1)
```

Sample run -

```
In [89]: A = np.arange(50)+1;

In [90]: A.reshape(-1,5).mean(1)
Out[90]: array([  3.,   8.,  13.,  18.,  23.,  28.,  33.,  38.,  43.,  48.])
```

Runtime test :

An alternative method to get those average values would be with the old-fashioned way of computing the sum and then dividing by the number of elements involved in the summation. Let's time these two methods -

```
In [107]: A = np.arange(500000)+1;

In [108]: %timeit A.reshape(-1,500).mean(1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.19 ms per loop

In [109]: %timeit A.reshape(-1,500).sum(1)/500.0
1000 loops, best of 3: 583 µs per loop
```

Seems, like quite an improvement there with the alternative method! But wait, it's because with `mean` method NumPy is converting to float type by default and that conversion overhead showed up here.

So, if we use float type input arrays, we would have a different and a fair scenario -

```
In [144]: A = np.arange(500000).astype(float)+1;

In [145]: %timeit A.reshape(-1,500).mean(1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 534 µs per loop

In [146]: %timeit A.reshape(-1,500).sum(1)/500.0
1000 loops, best of 3: 516 µs per loop
```

---

**MATLAB**

With column-major ordering, we would reshape to have `500` rows and then average along the first dimension -

```
mean(reshape(A,500,[]),1)
```

Sample run -

```
>> A = 1:50;                      
>> mean(reshape(A,5,[]),1)        
ans =
     3     8    13    18    23    28    33    38    43    48
```

Runtime test :

Let's try out the old-fashioned way here too -

```
>> A = 1:500000;
>> func1 = @() mean(reshape(A,500,[]),1);
>> timeit(func1)                         
ans =
    0.0013021
>> func2 = @() sum(reshape(A,500,[]),1)/500.0;
>> timeit(func2)                              
ans =
    0.0012291
```

Comment: Probably `reshape(A,[],1000)` makes more sense, given the question definition

Comment: @LuisMendo Hmm I guess I was looking the other way of using the length of each section.

Comment: `np.mean(x)` is basically equivalent to `np.sum(x, dtype=float) / 500` here. Your `sum` without the `dtype` is faster because it does `uint32` addition not `float64` addition, at the risk of overflow. It's not that matlab is being smart, it's that it's being more cautious

Comment: @Eric Absolutely! Let me add that comment into the post, thanks!

Comment: @Divakar: Wasn't expecting the overhead to actually be in the int->float conversion, but I guess I shouldn't be surprised. So I guess `int+float` is slower than both `int + int` and `float + float`

Comment: Rather than `astype`, you can just do `np.arange(500000.)` to make it a float, or do `np.arange(1, 500001.)` to avoid the ` + 1`.

Comment: @TheBlackCat Useful tip that one! Would keep that in mind, thanks.